# Add Texture to Unlit Transparent Color Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, oculus, cg

How can I add a `Texture` to following shader given by Oculus API for fading :

```
Shader "Oculus/Unlit Transparent Color" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {} //  I added this property to apply Texture. Where can I use it?
}

SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
    LOD 100
    Fog {Mode Off}
    Cull Off
    ZWrite Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Color [_Color]

    Pass {}
}
}
```

Comment: **About all the downvoters** If you are sure that _This question does not show research effort;it is unclear and not useful._ then you should justify that by adding a proper comment. If you are down voting the question because of _meta effect_ and you can't downvote the answer because you don't want to lose the reputation then such herd behavior is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [xyLe_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1861380/xyle) suggested in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742399/17034), In `Pass{}`block I added following code and it worked:

```
  SetTexture [_MainTex] {
            constantColor [_Color]
            Combine texture * primary DOUBLE, texture * constant
        }
```

Comment: You should have marked his answer as correct.  If it was lacking anything you only needed to tell him, or add it in an edit.

Comment: This answer has been discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332723/answer-your-question-copying-an-answer-and-mark-yours-as-accepted

Answer (score 30):

You can use the property you have added in the `Pass {}` which should contain at least a vertex and a fragment shader (or a surface shader).

In the pass you define a `sampler2D` with the same name as you property, so you can use it in your shader functions.

There are some examples shaders in unitys documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShaderTut2.html 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderExamples.html

**Edit**
There is also an example for shaders that are structured like yours:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShaderTut1.html 
According to this, you can add something like

```
SetTexture [_MainTex] {
    // some properties
}
```

So in a similar fashion like setting the Color.
(Sorry I haven't used shaders structured like that yet, only vertex/fragment shaders, so you will have to try if it works and/or read up the examples provided by unity or wait for another answer of someone with more expertise :) )